# Clone Each and Append to Each

Tags: jquery

I'm cloning EACH title and using insertBefore to place each title above the content div, but its inserting ALL the titles above EACH div.

What am I doing wrong with my approach? I just want EACH title above EACH div (not all in each)

```
$(".modAcTitle").each(function(){
    var newLink = $(this).clone();
    $(newLink).each(function (index) {
        $(newLink).insertBefore('.content').index()
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m73ot4zh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target each instance of the `.content` element you want to add the cloned element to by its index using `eq()`. Try this:

```
$(".modAcTitle").each(function(i) {
    var $content = $('.content').eq(i);
    $(this).clone().prependTo($content);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m73ot4zh/1/)